# Detecting AJAX call in a Django view function

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, request-headers

I need Ajax functionality in my Django application.
Therefore, a jQuery code calls a Django view function that returns data (here in a simplified form).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Prevent the form from being submitted normally
    $('#filter-form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/filter_view/',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', //Necessary to work with request.is_ajax()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is the verification - in the Django view -, that it received an Ajax call. Previously, this could be done by 'is_ajax()', but this function is deprecated.

It was replaced, then, by

```
 if request.method == 'POST' and request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
```

or

```
if accept_header == 'application/json' or x_requested_with_header == 'XMLHttpRequest':
```

That all worked. All of a sudden, it did not work anymore, because, although the headers were declared in the AJAX code,

```
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', //Necessary to work with request.is_ajax()
        }
```

they do not arrive in the Django view. Nothing was changed in the Django middleware. The Chrome browser, used for debugging of the JQuery code, was reset.
I dont have the slightest idea, why the headers settings do not get through.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at your symptomps you probabably have submit event without `event.preventDefault()` so normal HTTP request is sent. This is the only explanation. Another idea is that your submit event throw an error before you call preventDefault(). Try enabling "preserve logs" option in Dev Tools.